# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently update my Android Studio to 3.0 version (from 2.3) and added some new sdk files and update Gradle to 3.0.0 (from 2.4-all).
But now when I test my app in a 4.2 android version cellphone it crash with this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.<init>(SupportActivity.java:68)
            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:28)
            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:34)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:75)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:60)
            at com.bachecubano.elbache.IntroActivity.<init>(IntroActivity.java:23)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2090)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:   145 cannot locate '__isnanf'...
```

My head breaks when I make a new project and testing works fine!

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 29
        versionName "1.12"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':android-rate')
    implementation project(':okhttp-3.10.0')
    implementation project(':okio-1.14.0')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```